# When do we use dash instead of equality sign?

Tags: notation

I began reading ["A Concise Introduction to Mathematical Logic"](http://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/raut/logic3/announce.pdf) by Wolfgang Rautenberg and on the 17th page came up with the following notation:
[image]

The author (as I can understand) uses dash sign instead of equality sign but I've never met such notation. Is it specific to Germany, to mathematical logic texts, or something else?

Comment: Try zooming in.

Comment: The problem was with the PDF viewer and I was stupid enough not to open document in another one.

Comment: The problem is the viewer, not you!

Comment: The main thing is that now i can read a book without questioning the notation.

Comment: Mathematics does not make mistakes ! it is only in "applied" mathematics (like coding software), being performed by human (and limited) being, that you can find errors ... Of course, I'm joking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears as $=$ to me (and is on xix). Check the PDF viewer you are using.

Comment: You're right. It was my viewer joking with me.